# CQL (cassandra) - Select only the rows with maximum value in one of the columns

Tags: cassandra, cql

I need to find the rows with given stationid, that have time1 greater than specified time and maximal time2.

The table is created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE forec (
    stationid int,
    time1 timestamp,
    time2 timestamp,
    value double,
    PRIMARY KEY ((stationid), time1, time2)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time1 DESC)
```

Lets suppose the data in the table is like this:

```
    +------------+-----------------------+----------------------+--------+
    | stationid  | time1                 |  time2               |  value |
    +------------+-----------------------+----------------------+--------+
    | 1          | 2020-10-21 06:00:00   | 2020-10-21 05:00:00  | 1      |                                  
    | 1          | 2020-10-21 06:00:00   | 2020-10-21 04:00:00  | 2      |                                   
    | 1          | 2020-10-21 06:00:00   | 2020-10-21 03:00:00  | 3      |                                   
    | 1          | 2020-10-21 05:00:00   | 2020-10-21 04:00:00  | 4      |
    | 1          | 2020-10-21 05:00:00   | 2020-10-21 03:00:00  | 5      |
    | 1          | 2020-10-21 04:00:00   | 2020-10-21 02:00:00  | 6      |
    +------------+-----------------------+----------------------+--------+
```

I would like to query:
Give me all the rows where stationid = 1 and time1 >= 2020-10-21 05:00:00 and time2 has maximum value. The query should return the following rows:

```
    +------------+-----------------------+----------------------+--------+
    | stationid  | time1                 |  time2               |  value |
    +------------+-----------------------+----------------------+--------+
    | 1          | 2020-10-21 06:00:00   | 2020-10-21 05:00:00  | 1      |        
    | 1          | 2020-10-21 05:00:00   | 2020-10-21 04:00:00  | 4      | 
    +------------+-----------------------+----------------------+--------+
```

I know I could query like:

```
SELECT * FROM forec WHERE stationid = 1 AND time1 >= '2020-10-21 05:00:00';
```

and then filter the results on client (and keep only the rows that have maximum time2), however I would like to know if this can be done more efficiently (filtering results on the Cassandra side).

Or maybe I should change the table model?

Comment: Not really - the CQL has quite limited functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: According to [Cassandra document](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/dml.html#grouping-results), "If a column is selected without an aggregate function, in a statement with a GROUP BY, the first value encounter in each group will be returned." So below example only works when `time2` is stored in `DESC` order.

If you are using recent version of Cassandra (like 3.11.x) then you can use `GROUP BY` to do things like

```
SELECT
  stationid,
  time1,
  max(time2) AS max_time2,
  value
FROM
  forec
WHERE
  stationid = 1
AND
  time1 >= '2020-10-21 05:00:00'
GROUP BY time1;
```

and you get

```
cqlsh:test> SELECT stationid, time1, max(time2) as max_time2, value FROM forec WHERE stationid = 1 AND time1 >= '2020-10-21 05:00:00' GROUP BY  time1;

 stationid | time1                           | max_time2                       | value
-----------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+-------
         1 | 2020-10-21 06:00:00.000000+0000 | 2020-10-21 05:00:00.000000+0000 |     1
         1 | 2020-10-21 05:00:00.000000+0000 | 2020-10-21 04:00:00.000000+0000 |     4

(2 rows)
```

Note that this scans your partition so be aware of partition size, especially when you use timestamp in clustering column.

Comment: I've tried this - however it seems that the value is not guaranteed to be the "correct one" (the one that belongs to the greatest time2 in a group). According to documentation (https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/dml.html):   If a column is selected without an aggregate function, in a statement with a GROUP BY, the first value encounter in each group will be returned. And the first value might not be "the rigth one"... Am I missing something?

Comment: maybe it would be possible to define UDA/UDF that would be applied on the "value" column (after GROUP BY) in order to retrieve the value that belongs to the greatest time2 in each of the groups? Anybody knows how?

Comment: yeah, you are right, I tested with time2 DESC but when its ordering is ASC, `value` is the first encountered value, as the cassandra doc points out. If you can change order of time2 as DESC, then you will always have max value of time2 in the first row of time1 group and can get value column associated to it.

Comment: your solution works if time2 is ordered as DESC and as long as GROUP BY maintains original order of rows (and apparently it does). In this case you can omit the max on time2 - "the first encounter" value for the time2 will be the "rigth one" (i.e. the maximum one) - the same way as it holds true for the "value". In case the order of time2 cannot be changed to DESC I've come up with a solution using UDF/UDAs - the solution is provided in the answer...

Answer (score 1):

The solution using UDA/UDFs:

State function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION curValState ( state tuple<timestamp,double>, time timestamp, value double ) CALLED ON NULL INPUT RETURNS tuple<timestamp, double> LANGUAGE java AS 'if (time != null && value != null) { if(state == null) {com.datastax.driver.core.TupleType tupleType = com.datastax.driver.core.TupleType.of(com.datastax.driver.core.ProtocolVersion.NEWEST_SUPPORTED, com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.DEFAULT_INSTANCE, com.datastax.driver.core.DataType.timestamp(), com.datastax.driver.core.DataType.cdouble()); state = tupleType.newValue(time, value);} else {if(state.getTimestamp(0).compareTo(time)<0){ state.setTimestamp(0, time); state.setDouble(1, value);}}} return state;';
```

Final function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION finalVal ( state tuple<timestamp, double> ) CALLED ON NULL INPUT RETURNS double LANGUAGE java AS 'return state.getDouble(1);';
```

Aggregate function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AGGREGATE valueatlatesttime (timestamp, double) SFUNC curValState STYPE tuple<timestamp, double> FINALFUNC finalVal INITCOND null;
```

The query:

```
SELECT
  stationid,
  time1,
  max(time2) AS max_time2,
  valueatlatesttime(time2, value) AS value_at_max_time2
FROM
  forec
WHERE
  stationid = 1
AND
  time1 >= '2020-10-21 05:00:00'
GROUP BY time1;
```